# SMTP endpoint fails to authenticate if empty string for user name is used

Tags: mule

My SMTP endpoint configuration looks like:

```
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp.host}" port="${smtp.port}" from="${smtp.from}" user="${smtp.user}" password="${smtp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
```

Properties are taken from properties file and works perfect if all properties are filled up and are not empty. But in cases when I don't wan't to use authentication, I change smtp.user and smtp.password to empty strings:

```
smtp.user=
smtp.password=
```

Then I just get

```
535 5.7.0 authentication failed
```

Seems like endpoint tries to authenticate with empty user name and password.
If I remove "user" and "password" attributes from endpoint xml, it works just fine, but it isn't an option for me because in some deployments I need authentication in some I don't. So I'd like to configure it using my properties file. Any solutions for it?

Thanks in advance.

Geddis

Answer (score 0):

Use a choice router with two routes, one for the authenticated SMTP outbound endpoint (using a condition in `when` that checks for non-emptiness of `${smtp.user}`) and the other for the non-authenticated endpoint (in the `otherwise`).